# How to generate reports in PMD using Command Line

Tags: pmd

We can launch PMD on CMD with this command

pmd.bat c:\path\to\my\src xml c:\path\to\mycustomrules.xml

Where is it generating the reports???

I mean in which location?

Answer (score 1):

I found it...

simply type on CMD

pmd.bat c:\path\to\my\src xml c:\path\to\mycustomrules.xml > myfile.txt

Answer (score 0):

You can use reportfile argument for this.

Example is

> pmd SourcePath html basic -reportfile C:\PMDReports\PMDoutput.html

OR

> pmd SourcePath html basic -reportfile PMDoutput.html

Incase 2 PMDoutput.html is found in current directory.